# document.getElementById is not changing the styles dynamically in my React component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a button that I need the background color and inner text to on click. I tried the  document.getElementById method but it is not applying the changes. How to I solve this issue?

```
<TableBody>
    {
        records === null ?
        []
        :
        records.map((item, index) => (
            <button className="addToggle" id={"addToggle" + index} onClick={() => handleAddSwitch(item, index)}>
                <CircleCheckIcon />
                Add
            </button>
        ))
    }
</TableBody>


function handleAddSwitch(item, index) {
    document.getElementById("addToggle" + index).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("addToggle" + index).innerHTML= "Added";
}
```

Comment: I have tried creating sample. It works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-resonance-mqw3m

Try checking what is the value of`item,index` in `handleAddSwitch`

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I logged the values and they are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.target` OR `event.currentTarget`:

```
<button className="addToggle" id={"addToggle" + index} onClick={(e) => handleAddSwitch(e, index)}>
    <CircleCheckIcon />
    Add
</button>
```

**Function**

```
const handleAddSwitch(e, index) => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    e.target.innerHTML= "Added";
}
```

Comment: it worked but it deleted the icon <CircleCheckIcon />, how do I solve this?

Comment: insert **Add** to `span` element then: e.target.children[1].innerHTML = "...";

Comment: e.target.children[1] is undefined

Comment: at the first, append **Add** to span, then **Log** it: `e.target.children`

Comment: @Nour If it works, please confirm it